# Jquery ajax, return error message With Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

I'm doing a like/dislike button which works fine.

I'm trying now to implement a loading since the like/dislike script will have to calculate and update few more stuff that can be quite heavy.

I'd like to return some error messages in case something failed during the script execution. 
When i alert the data that has been returned, instead of having the value of the string that i returned in my php i have a full html of my actual page.

I'd like to know where i am doing wrong.

Here my Controller :

```
public function likeAction()
{


    $this->getWILikesTable()->like($this->params()->fromRoute('id'),
    $this->params()->fromQuery('value_like', 1), $this->identity()->id);

    if($this->getWITable()->getWI($id)){
        $wi = $this->getWITable()->getWI($id);
    }
    else{
        return 'Error : Work item ID does not exist';
    }

    //Update WI status to under discussion = 2 if the WI is new
    if($wi->status == 0){

        $this->getWITable()->updateStatus(2, id);

        //Send Notification

        return 1;

    }

    //Update WI status to Approved by poster = 3 if score like of posters is above or equal to gate 1

        //Send Notification

    //Update WI status to Approved by expert = 4 if score like is expert of this field is above or equal to gate 2

        //Send Notification

    //Update WI status to under discussion if score of posters and score of experts are below requirement

        //Send Notification

    //return 1;

}
```

here my javascript :

```
$('.loading-box').css('display', 'block');

$.ajax({
    url: base_url+'/workitems/like/'+id,  
    data: {value_like: value_like},
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == 1){
            $('.loading-box').css('display', 'none');
        }
        else{
            alert(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it happens when you have something wrong in php

Comment: You are most likely generating a full page for the return from `base_url+'/workitems/like/'+id`. If you visit in a browser and see a full page then this is the issue. Generally a return to an Ajax call it Text,JSON,XML, etc. Check the header and see if the return is HTML then that is your issue

Comment: Ho okay, do you have any advises how to debug that since i can't see the result of my code or any errors?

Comment: @MattGreen thank you, i'll check that.

Comment: I see indeed a full page when i visit /workitems/like/'+id. I'm actually using zend framework 2 and by default the action is including the header the view and the footer so i guess i'm missing a point somewhere.

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698833/ajax-in-zend-framework2). I think this is close to what you are looking for.

Comment: @MattGreen thank you, this is indeed one of the solution i found. I'm still trying to find a better way as some zf2 experts advise me to not do so.

I'll came back with the solution!

Comment: If the "like/dislike script" is that expensive, you really should cache its result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i finally manage to do it with a proper Zf2 way.

```
protected $acceptCriteria = array(
    'Zend\View\Model\JsonModel' => array('application/json'),
    'Zend\View\Model\ViewModel' => array('text/html'),
);

public function likeAction()
{

    $viewmodel  = $this->acceptableviewmodelselector($this->acceptCriteria);

    if ($viewmodel instanceof \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel) {

        $this->getWILikesTable()->like($this->params()->fromRoute('id'), $this->params()->fromQuery('value_like', 1), $this->identity()->id);

        if($this->getWITable()->getWI($id)){
            $wi = $this->getWITable()->getWI($id);
        }
        else{
            $result = array('status' => false, 'message' => 'Error : Work item ID does not exist');
        }

        //Update WI status to under discussion = 2 if the WI is new
        if($wi->status == 0){

            $this->getWITable()->updateStatus(2, id);

            //Send Notification

            $result = array('status' => true, 'message' => '');

        }

        //Update WI status to Approved by poster = 3 if score like of posters is above or equal to gate 1

            //Send Notification

        //Update WI status to Approved by expert = 4 if score like is expert of this field is above or equal to gate 2

            //Send Notification

        //Update WI status to under discussion if score of posters and score of experts are below requirement

            //Send Notification


    }

    $result = array('status' => true, 'message' => '');

    $viewmodel->setVariables($result);

    return $viewmodel;

}
```

This is the javascript :

$('.loading-box').css('display', 'block');

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url+'/workitems/like/'+id,  
    data: {value_like: value_like},
    success: function(result) {
        if(result.status == true){
            $('.loading-box').css('display', 'none');
        }
        else{
            alert(result.message);
        }
    }
});
```

And should not forgot to register in application module, module.config.php

```
'strategies' => array(
    'ViewJsonStrategy',
),
```